# TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.dataSource.map') react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

Soy nuevo en React Native y estaba siguiendo un tutorial de como parsear un JSON y casi en el paso final me ha saltado este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema viene cuando (después de asegurarme que el contenido se ha cargado en el primer if) intento asignara a la variable 'movies' el contenido que recoge del JSON. Este es el código:

```
import  React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  ActivityIndicator
} from 'react-native';


export default class App extends React.Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      isLoading:true,
      dataSource:null,
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    return fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json')
        .then( (response) => response.json())
        .then( (responseJson) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoading:false,
            dateSource: responseJson.movies,
          })
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
          console.log(error)
        });
  }


  render() {
    if(this.state.isLoading){
      return (
          <View style={stylesss.container}>
            <ActivityIndicator/>
          </View>
      )
    } else {

      let movies = this.state.dataSource.map((value, key) => {
        return <View key={key} style={stylesss.item}>
              <Text>{val.title}</Text>
            </View>
      });

      return (
          <View style={stylesss.container}>
            <Text>{movies}</Text>
          </View>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Si alguien me pudiese ayudar, se lo agradecería un montón

Comment: La razón de porque no ves nada en pantalla es porque en el `setState` tienes `dateSource` y no `dataSource` como defines en tu state. Con respecto a la respuesta que te dieron ya

Answer (score 0):

Los states deberías inicializarlos dependiendo el tipo de valor que esperas, en este caso, `dataSource` va a ser un Array, pero hasta que no tenga datos va a ser `null`, es decir que la primera vez, va a tratar de hacer un `null.map()` que es incorrecto. Si cambias la inicialización a:

```
this.state= {
      isLoading:true,
      dataSource:[], //<-- Array vacío en lugar de null
    }
```

no va a romper porque va a hacer `[].map()` que no es incorrecto.

Cuando el `fetch` termine, va a cambiar el state y va a mostrar los datos siempre que `responseJson.movies` sea un Array.

Cuidado que en `<Text>{val.title}</Text>` deberías poner `<Text>{value.title}</Text>`

Comment: Ahora no me sale el error, pero no me saca nada por pantalla. Como si el Array estuviera vacío. No entiendo porque al chico del video le funcionaba sin problema: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1JQwaIds7A&t=721s

Comment: eso puede ser o bien porque el ajax no retorna nada o bien porque retorna vacía esa propiedad, si te fijas en la pestaña network (o red) del navegador deberías poder ver si el ajax se hace o no y que es lo que devuelve.

Comment: La razón de porque no ves nada en pantalla es porque en el `setState` tienes `dateSource` y no `dataSource` como defines en tu state

Comment: Buen punto, @nerviosus fíjate en lo que menciona Germán aquí arriba. Tienes también un typo.

Comment: Qué vergüenza, no me había dado cuenta. Me pasa siempre con WebStorm, creo que no leo bien los errores. Bueno, muchísimas gracias a los dos.